# Does MySQL always run foreign key constraint checks when a row is updated? Or only when a relevant column is changed?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, foreign-keys, constraints, innodb

I have this question and I haven't found specific documentation to confirm the behavior and am unaware of how to manually check this myself.

Consider I have table A with b_id foreign key to table B. If I run an update on a row in table A, does mysql always run the foreign key constraint check on table B even if A's b_id goes unchanged or isn't passed in the update statement? such as `(select 1 from B where id = ?)`

Example:

`UPDATE A set A.name = "x", A.b_id = 1 where A.id = 1` I know this runs the foreign key check on B

`UPDATE A set A.name = "x" where A.id = 1` But does this also run the foreign key check even though b_id goes unchanged since it was not passed?

`UPDATE A set A.name = "x" A.b_id = A.b_id where A.id = 1` And what about this? b_id gets passed in with same existing value. Does the fk check run?

Any supporting documentation or help would be appreciated, as well as tips on how I can test this sort of behavior myself since using EXPLAIN doesn't help.

Edit: this is for INNODB engine and mysql 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a foreign key constraint, [MySQL requires an index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/constraint-foreign-key.html):

> MySQL requires that foreign key columns be indexed; if you create a table with a foreign key constraint but no index on a given column, an index is created.

To clarify, this is an index in the referencing table (in your example A), not the referenced table (in your example B). The index in table B you have to provide yourself, otherwise you will get an error message.

Given this index, the answer to your question can be summarized to:

**The foreign key constraint will be verified (e.g. the check if the row exists in the referenced table) whenever this index will be modified.**

Since it may not be completely obvious when this happens, some examples: for a sample table of

```
CREATE TABLE A (id int primary key, b_id int, c int, 
    FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES B(id))
```

the foreign key (e.g. if the value exists in the referenced table B) is checked for (assuming that such a row exists):

```
update A set id = 2 where id = 1
```

as it modifies the primary key, which is part of every index, so that hidden index gets modified, thus the verification will be executed, and

```
update A set b_id = 3 where b_id = 2
```

as it modifies the column b_id, which is part of the hidden index, so that hidden index gets modified.

It does NOT get checked for

```
update A set id = 2 where id = 2 
update A set b_id = 3 where b_id = 3
update A set b_id = b_id
```

as those do not modify the index content (because nothing changes).

Notably

```
update A set c = 2 where c = 3
```

also does not modify the index (as c is not part of the index), so the foreign key constraint is not verified even though the row itself changes.

To make things a bit more complicated, you can use your own index:

```
CREATE TABLE A (id int primary key, b_id int, c int, 
    INDEX b_c (b_id, c),
    FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES B(id))
```

If you do that, MySQL can use this index for your foreign key and doesn't have to add its own hidden index. The effects of the updates mentioned above will not change, except for

```
update A set c = 2 where c = 3
```

as now, c is a column of the index that MySQL uses for the foreign key constraint, abd this update requires a modification of the index content - and thus triggers a verification. This is actually a verification that logically would not be required - it just happens because of how MySQL implemented it. So if you really want to prevent every unnecessary check, you could add an index on just column `b_id` yourself, then MySQL won't use the index on `(b_id, c)`. But that would be extreme micro-optimization and you really should not do it just for this.

Please note that, while this may be an interesting technical detail to know, it should not have any impact on what you actually do with the database. You should not write your queries differently with that knowledge. If you need to update a row, you have to update the row. Also, adding an index just to prevent a check will most certainly not help. Also, since the behaviour is not specified, it can also change at any time (e.g. by you if you find and implement a better solution).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this actually makes a lot more sense, that mysql would use issue the check based on the index being changed rather than the row from the table itself.

Comment: The reason I asked is because some ORMs will pass in additional columns when running update statements, so I wanted to avoid unnecessary overhead, but now I realize it's no issue. Thanks

Comment: Yes, adding additional columns won't be an issue (for the foreign key check). But I want to emphasize again, this would be a micro-optimization kind of thing. MySQL does so many other things in the background, details like this should not matter when you think about optimizing your sql/orm code. But even better that MySQL does what you hoped it does.

Comment: *The foreign key constraint will be verified (e.g. the check if the row exists in the referenced table) whenever this index will be modified.* FK can be checked by any index where the index expression prefix is FK expression (this index not needed to be UNIQUE even!). [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=24af36b9579c0bb983b3d4dc7193a4f7). Imagine that one index needed in modifying whereas the second one does not need... The rule is ambiguous and cannot be used as a criteria or as a prove.

Comment: @Akina The index that I mean is the index in the referencing table (e.g. the table with the constraint, t2 in your demo), not the referenced table (t1 in your demo). (I had tried to clarify that with my 2nd paragraph). MySQL will pick an index or create one; if there are several available (that start with the correct column(s)), it can indeed be a bit arbitrary which one it will be. Nevertheless, it will be one. And that one determines when the (internal) check gets executed. It's just the technical implementation choice the developers made (and has basically no effect for the enduser).

Answer (score 2):

Foreign key integrity is checked always when the server detects that the data is changed by fact and needs in save to the disk. It is checked after all BEFORE UPDATE triggers execution (rather than data type check which is performed each time, before and after each separate trigger).

The reason is simple. Server does not store any flag which marks does the value is changed - it is more expensive than direct compare before real, physical, UPDATE execution. The value changing is not tracked. Server does not know does the value to be saved during the update is provided by the query text or, for example, is provided by one of the BEFORE UPDATE triggers in the trigger chain.

[small DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=94451d3db69ecf964d682c81ad0e565a)

Comment: Thanks for your response, do you have any documentation sources that further explains how foreign key integrity checks are triggered?

Comment: @user3509128 Each constraint is checked independtly and in these moments when this makes sense. You must investigate source code for to ensure - I doubt that this is documented separately.

Comment: This is actually not correct (or at least missing some details). MySQL has a way to track changes, and especially for foreign key value changes: if it has to modify the foreign key index in the referencing table.

Comment: @Solarflare *MySQL has a way to track changes, and especially for foreign key value changes: if it has to modify the foreign key index in the referencing table.* You tell about another tracking, it seems. I tell about tracking between UPDATE sent to the server and updated data sent to the disk - i.e. within single UPDATE query execution.

Comment: @Akina Yes, we are probably talking about a different kind of change tracking. It is just that foreign key checks are applied as part of the internal logical execution before anything is supposed to be written to disk (as if the check would fail, it obviously should not get to the part where something is written to disk). I know, this is not what you said, neverthessless, I think this doesn't answer what the op wanted to know.